# Viber: Extract contact numbers & Names of a one particular VIBER group

Tags: viber

I'm in a certain Viber group. I need the contact numbers & names of people who in  a ONE GROUP name into an Excel/CSV file/

I tried some methods mentioned here, but it just extracts all the numbers. (I just need a number of a one given group name only)

https://itectec.com/superuser/windows-retrieve-export-contacts-from-viber-pc-version/

But this is not what I need.
Can someone help me???

Thanks